# How do I edit a (Default) or (Standard) RegKey using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, registrykey

I'm creating an Excel that need to be opened always in a new instance. To do so I decided to edit some RegKey via VBA when it opens.

My problem is to edit a RegKey that doesn't have a name, a (Default) or a (Standard).

To add a normal RegKey I have no problem:

```
RegKeyPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\DisableMergeInstance"
```

The default RegKey doesn't work at all:

```
RegKeyPath = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\command\(Default)"
```

My code:

```
Private Sub RegKeyUpdate()

    Dim RegKeyPath As String
    Dim RegKeyValue As String
    Dim RegKeyType As String

    RegKeyPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\DisableMergeInstance"
    RegKeyValue = "1"
    RegKeyType = "REG_DWORD"

    RegKeySave RegKeyPath, RegKeyValue, RegKeyType

    RegKeyPath = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\command\(Default)"
    RegKeyValue = RegKeyRead(RegKeyPath) & " /x"
    RegKeyType = "REG_SZ"

    RegKeySave RegKeyPath, RegKeyValue, RegKeyType

End Sub
```

```
Function RegKeyRead(RegKeyPath As String) As String

    Dim objRegistryKey As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objRegistryKey = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    RegKeyRead = objRegistryKey.RegRead(RegKeyPath)

    If 1 <> 1 Then
ErrorHandler:
        On Error GoTo 0
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If

End Function
```

```
Public Sub RegKeySave(RegKeyPath As String, RegKeyValue As String, Optional RegKeyType As String)

    Dim objRegistryKey As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objRegistryKey = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    objRegistryKey.RegWrite RegKeyPath, RegKeyValue, RegKeyType

    If 1 <> 1 Then
ErrorHandler:
        On Error GoTo 0
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If

End Sub
```

I expect to discover a way to add not only a new RegKey, but to add a new "folder" of RegKeys and edit its default value.